# Возможно ли создать свою функцию в less?

Tags: less

Нужно сделать функцию, которая будет возвращать определенное значение, вот пример с миксином

```css
.font-rem(@pixels) {
 font-size: @pixels/16rem;
}
```

Данный миксин переводит пиксели в ремы, но он делает это только для шрифта.

Как мне сделать такое: я пишу что-то вроде

`font-size: rem(16);` В итоге функция переведет аргумент в `rem` и вернет число

Полазив по документации, я ничего не нашел, про значение, возвращаемое функцией или миксином, возможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: `В итоге функция переведет аргумент в rem и вернет число` - в каком смысле переведет ***аргумент в rem*** куда вернет ***число*** ? Не совсем понял суть вопроса

Comment: Я хочу сделать свою собственную функцию, типа как в js function rem(px) { return px/16+'rem' };

А потом использовать в css типа font-size: rem(16);

Comment: Увы...`less` на это не способен...